# Explanation why a list with different types is a valid Haskell expression needed

Tags: list, haskell, types

So in an exercise I am given a list like `["xyz", True, 42]`. The question was if that is a valid expression in Haskell and what the type of that expression is.

A list can only hold homogenous types but the type of `"xyz"`is `[Char]`, the type of `True` is `Bool` and the type of `42` is `Num p => p`. That is different types so I can't put them into a list.

That's what I thought. But the given answer to that exercise is "Yes, it is a valid expression. Show-instance!."

Why is it a valid expression although the types of the list elements are different and what is meant with show-instance? I'm thinking of something like superclasses from object oriented languages but I thought this is not how Haskell works.

Comment: What "exercise" are you doing? Your thinking is pretty much spot on.

Comment: Where did you get that exercise? My best guess is that they thought the type was something like `[Show a => a]`, which isn’t how Haskell works, as you said.

Comment: The exercise is meant as exam-preparation and was given and answered from my lecturer.

Comment: Well strictly speaking we can make `instance Num Bool`, and `instance IsString Bool`, and thus construct a list of booleans with this.

Comment: Your lecturer might just be wrong, then…? (Fun fact: you can make it work by making `IsString Bool` and `Num Bool` instances, but that has nothing to do with `Show`.)

Comment: I sent him a message and asked for an explanation. I will let you know his answer.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I completely agree, but asking questions which rely on subtle GHC extensions like overloaded strings fells very un-academic to me. In my experience, a lecturer usually focuses on the general CS ideas rather than the details of a particular language/technology/piece of software which become completely irrelevant in other contexts. I could understand relying on overloaded numeric literals, at most, but not overloaded strings. That just sounds evil. I wonder if the OP correctly understood the question/answer -- it looks quite strange indeed.

Comment: I gave you the whole information that I am given in my post. "What is the type of `["xyz",False,42]`? Is that a valid expression in Haskell at all?" with a hint on the solution: "Yes, it is. Show-Instance!". As I asked my lecturer about this exercise he pointed me to Existential types. I wrote an answer that uses an instance of Show with Existential types and I think that is what my lecturer wanted. Anyway, my answer would still be "no, without extension and further ado this is no valid expression in Haskell."

Answer (score 6):

If we are allowed to define some more context, we can make this a valid expression, for instance with:

```
import Data.String(IsString(fromString))

instance IsString Bool where
    fromString [] = False
    fromString _ = True

instance Num Bool where
    (+) = (||)
    (*) = (&&)
    abs = id
    signum = id
    fromInteger 0 = False
    fromInteger _ = True
    negate = not
```

(here I used the truthiness of Python to convert from an `Integer` and `String` literal)

Then we can write it with the `OverloadedStrings` pragma:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

the_list = ["xyz", True, 42]
```

This will then be equivalent to:

```
Prelude Data.String> ["xyz", True, 42]
[True,True,True]
```

But note that the list still contains only `Bool`s, we only made `Bool` an instance of `IsString` and `Num` to enable us to convert string *literals* and number *literals* to `Bool`s.

A list of heterogeneous types is not possible in Haskell, and since by default a `Bool` is not a `Num`, we thus can not parse that expression without adding some extra magic.

An additional note is that it is valid Haskell *grammar*: syntactically there is nothing wrong, it is only in the next stage of the compiler: type checking, etc. that it will raise errors, since the syntax is *nonsensical*.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. It is nothing I would have come up with at my current state of Haskell-expertise.

Comment: @Lyndra: well I agree that it is making a lot of assumptions, and specific compiler features, so personally I would say that the answer to the question is *no, that expression is invalid*, but of course one can start nitpicking.

Comment: @Lyndra Indeed, you should not be expected to learn Haskell at this level of detail during a CS course. I'd expect that, in a CS course, the intended answer is "no, that can not be typed", as Willem also states. You should ask your instructor about this -- maybe you misunderstood the question/answer, or they simply wrote the wrong answer :)

Answer (score 0):

My lecturer gave me a hint to check for [Existential types](https://wiki.haskell.org/Heterogenous_collections#Existential_types) in Haskell.

I produced a working example from the description from the link above:

```
    {-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

    module Main where

    data Showable = forall a . Show a => MkShowable a
    pack:: Show a => a -> Showable
    pack a= MkShowable a

    instance Show Showable where
        show (MkShowable a) = show a

    hlist :: [Showable]
    hlist = [pack "xyz", pack True, pack 42]

    main :: IO ()
    main = do
        putStrLn "Heterogenous list 'camouflaged' as Showable:"
        print hlist
```

This works and produces indeed the input from the exercise. The datatype extension for Existential Quantification in the first line is necessary.

My explanation (I might have gotten something wrong though):

1. I create a new type `Showable`with one constructor `MkShowable` that takes any value `a` as long as it is in typeclass `Show` and thus makes a `Showable` out of it.
2. The method pack makes a `Show a` become a `Showable` by using the constructor `MkShowable` I described in 1.
3. `Showable` is made an instance of `Show`-typeclass and tells that if a `Showable`(`MkShowable a`) is to be shown, simply show `a`. So we can easily print our `Showable`s.

Furthermore I created a (heterogenous) list `hlist` of type `[Showable]`and packed the values from my example into it, using `pack`. The list is printed in the main function.

This really reminds me of object-oriented programming.

Comment: This is absolutely not what is being asked. The question is not whether you can put an Int and a Bool and a String to the same list, but whether a certain expression typechecks. You have made up a totally different expression and created an environment where it typechecks. That would be zero points for this exercise.

Comment: The output from the exercise…? I thought the exercise was just an input?

Comment: You are right. The input from the exercise equals the output of my program.